# Rails - How to display description from lookup table in view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a very simple question I'm sure. I have a table of static data containing a code and a description:

Code=A, Description=Table

Code=B, Description=Chair

Code=C, Description=Desk

The static data is maintained by users in a "Item Types" form. This has its own model/object/views.

I have another model "Items" where I store the Code. If I want to display the Description in the Jobs view, how can I do this please? As it currently stands, my view has:

`<td><%= p.item_type %></td>`

which displays "A" instead of "Table".

Thanks

Comment: Could you post the models (tables) your are using?

Comment: Okay, but note that I do not want to add any belongs_to or has_many clauses please. Here is the Item Types model: `class Itemtype < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :item_type, :add_on_value, :installation_price, :code
end`

Comment: And here is the basics of the Job Items model: `class Jobitem < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :job
  has_many :jobitemaddons, :dependent => :destroy

  attr_accessible :location, :item_type, :width, :height, :quantity, :initial_price, :installation, :installation_price, :job_id

end`

Comment: @brito, any ideas please? Or anyone else?

Comment: Okay I have sorted via belongs_to and has_many, though I must admit, I don't like this method, there must be some other way...